# Embedding Orbeon Form Builder into own website by using an API

Tags: orbeon

Can I embed Orbeon Forms (CE 4.7) form builder into my own website by using API? If so, is there an API I can use. If not, can I write it by myself because I am not sure whether orbeon supports Form Builder embedding or not. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this blog post: [Embedding support in Orbeon Forms 4.7](http://blog.orbeon.com/2014/09/embedding-support-in-orbeon-forms-47.html)

Also, the documentation:
[Form Runner ~ APIs ~ Server side Embedding](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-APIs-~-Server-side-Embedding). At the bottom, under Limitations, it says that embedding Form Builder is not currently not supported.

Do you need to embed the builder (form designer) or did you really want to embed Form Runner? If you need to embed the builder, then I don't know about that.

Also see: [Embedding and Proxying Orbeon Forms](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/contributor-guide/proxying-orbeon-forms).

And Orbeon supports a couple of ways to integrate with Liferay (although Liferay 6.2 is not yet supported). See:
[Deploying Orbeon Forms as a Portlet into Liferay](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/admin/deployment-portlet)
[Form Runner ~ Portal ~ Liferay Proxy Portlet Guide](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Portal-~-Liferay-Proxy-Portlet-Guide)

Comment: These links are not working anymore, and i need help with embedding via javascript.

Comment: @AttaH. I haven't worked with Orbeon for a few years now so my knowledge is out of date. I suggest you create a new question with the orbeon tag. The developers were pretty good about responding.